# What is the ApplicationsStorageExtension process on macOS?

Tags: cpu, activity-monitor

I heard my MacBook Air's fan running loudly, so I opened Activity Monitor. I see that a process named "ApplicationsStorageExtension" has a high number for % CPU. How do I kill that process?

Duplicates:

- [Process group "ApplicationsStorageExtension" eating my RAM? : MacOS - Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/gz32jn/process_group_applicationsstorageextension_eating/)
- [applicationstorageextension on big sur eating up memory - Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252119035)

Answer (score 28):

Did you leave About This Mac open with Storage selected?

I think ApplicationsStorageExtension calculates how much storage your Mac is using.

To stop it:

1. Choose About This Mac from [the Apple menu ](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/whats-in-the-apple-menu-mchlp1130/mac) (located in the top-left corner of your screen).
2. Close the window that appears.

Comment: This solution worked for me instantly.

Comment: Do you know what is it computing 24/7?